# why VS code has problem with variable name?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, frontend, visual-studio-code

Why vs code has problem when I write `let name = "Hi";`
it has problem with the name and i should change it to something like :sname , fname or etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [global variable `name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name) is predefined in browsers.

Your linter is complaining that you are trying to redeclare it in a global scope.

[image: VS code screenshot]

Comment: If they're using `let`, then there shouldn't be a problem

Comment: @NicholasTower — Tell that to the linter.